# Indices of matching of rows between matrices

Tags: r, matrix

Let n be a positive integer. We have a matrix B that has n columns, whose entries are integers between 1 and n. The aim is to match the rows of B with the rows of permutations(n), memorizing the indices in a vector v.

For example, let us consider the following. If

```
permutations(3)=
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    3    2
[3,]    2    1    3
[4,]    2    3    1
[5,]    3    1    2
[6,]    3    2    1
```

and

```
B=
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    3    1    2
[4,]    2    3    1
[5,]    3    1    2
```

Then the vector v is

```
1 1 5 4 5
```

because the first two rows of B are equal to the row number 1 of permutations(3), the third row of B is the row number 5 of permutations(3), and so on.

I tried to apply the command

```
 row.match
```

but the latter returns the error:

```
Error in do.call("paste", c(x[, , drop = FALSE], sep = "\r")) : 
second argument must be a list
```

Comment: what library does `permutations` come from?

Comment: @missuse Basic...

Comment: There is no base `permutations`. I think it's from package `e1071`

Comment: Interesting I have to load `library(e1071)` additionally when I do `?permutations` I am offered just the one from the mentioned library. Anyway Sotos already answered nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `match`,

```
match(do.call(paste, data.frame(B)), do.call(paste, data.frame(m1)))
#[1] 1 1 5 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to turn your matrices into dataframes and join them:

```
A = read.table(text = "
1    2    3
1    3    2
2    1    3
2    3    1
3    1    2
3    2    1
")

B = read.table(text = "
1    2    3
1    2    3
3    1    2
2    3    1
3    1    2
")

library(dplyr)

A %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>%
  right_join(B) %>%
  pull(row_id)

# [1] 1 1 5 4 5
```